# Comparing NTFS HFS+ EXT4 ZFS

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, ext4, zfs, hfs+

here's the thing, I need to investigate about these 4 filesystems for a college work but I can't find the right info on the web

The point is to compare these 4 and their features but I can't find benchmarks or detailed data for it

If someone can tell me all you know about the advantages and disadvantages of them or any website that has the information I need it would be awesome

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I only know zfs. ZFS has integrated filesystem and volume management. You create a pool of disks and carve out filesystems. You can have unlimited filesystems on a single pool. You can make it hybrid storage by adding ssd for log and read cache. Unlimited snapshots. ZFS uses COW so there is very little filesystem create time and on disk state is always considered valid. No fsck needed. Unlimited size.